# Numpy - create a multidimensional array of a copy of an array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, numpy-ndarray

I want to generate a an array of ordered numbers and then multiply it into another array :

```
[ [0,1,2,3,4,5] [0,1,2,3,4,5] [0,1,2,3,4,5] ... [0,1,2,3,4,5] ]
```

I can generate the first [0,1,2,3,4,5] with `nums = np.arange(0, 6)` but then if I multiply by a number inside a list it just increases the values = `[nums* 3] = [0,3,6,9,12,15]`.
How can I do this ?

Comment: Makes no sense. When you write multiply, you want to duplicate it X times and store it into a list ? That's not multiplication.

Comment: provide input and expected output

Comment: `np.repeat(np.arange(0, 6), (4, 1))`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using `numpy` methods ([`numpy.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html#numpy.repeat) and [`numpy.expand_dims`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.expand_dims.html)):

```
np.repeat(np.expand_dims(np.arange(0,6), axis=0), repeats=5, axis=0)

array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

Or, more simply:

```
np.repeat([np.arange(0,6)],repeats=5, axis=0)
```

The first method is useful if you were trying to expand a pre-existing one dimensional array. If you are trying to create your array from the start, the second method is more straightforward.

Answer (score 3):

BTW, why not simply use `np.array()` as in:

```
In [147]: nums = np.arange(6)

In [148]: nums
Out[148]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

In [149]: [nums] * 5
Out[149]: 
[array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]),
 array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])]

In [150]: np.array([nums] * 5)
Out[150]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

---

In one-line:

```
In [151]: np.array([np.arange(6)] * 5)
Out[151]: 
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

Answer (score 1):

you can't multiply a numpy array with a scalar and expect the same behaviour as multiplying a python list (or string) with a scalar.

for numpy, the multiplication operator will broadcast the multiplication over all the array elements:

i.e.

```
np.array([1,2,3]) * 2 == np.array([1*2, 2*2, 3*2) == np.array([2,4,6])
```

instead, you can use a list comprehension

```
np.array([np.arange(6) for _ in range(4)])
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

or generate a list of lists through multiplication and then convert to numpy array & reshape:

```
np.array([list(range(6))*4]).reshape(4,6)
array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
       [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]])
```

or, generate an array of shape (1,6) and repeat along the first axix:

```
np.repeat(np.arange(6).reshape(1,6), repeats=4, axis=0)
# produces the same output as the example outputs above.
```

Comment: The next answer makes the simple change of including the multiplication _inside_ the `np.array()` invocation. From the wording of your answer it would appear you were not aware of it.